# Can we use "a" after "many"? What does it mean, then?

Tags: grammar

Can we use "a" after "many"? What does it mean, then?

Example:

> Every living thing (and perhaps many a dead one as well) pays heed to that call. [source](http://www.eco-action.org/dt/thinking.html)

Comment: In many a situation you may.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use ***'a/an'*** after ***many***.
This is a more formal or old-fashioned expression I suppose.
Like the *adjective* - (She was depressed for *many* months) and
*pronoun* form (Some workers will be willing to work on sunday, but *many* will not.) of many, ***Many a/an*** is used to indicate a large number of something.
However it takes a singular noun.

Some Examples:
*She remained hidden from the public for **many a** year.* [for many years]
*I've been to Paris **many a** time.*  [= many times]
***Many a*** politician has promised to make changes. [*Politician* and *has* are singular].

Comment: Can we say "many a/an year" means more years than "many years"?

Comment: If you include the sentence that you're trying to use it in, it'd be better. For example, *for many a year it didn't rain.*.